# Creating JavaScript Phone Keypad with Alphabet for SMS

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to create a virtual phone keypad with alphabet feature for SMS. This is what I’ve tried so far:

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    input = document.querySelector('input'),
    busy = true,
    hold,
    is_busy,
    delay = 1000,
    change = -1,
    click = null;
for (var i = 0, len = button.length; i < len; ++i) {
    button[i].onmousedown = function(e) {
        var text = this.getAttribute('data-text').split(""),
            number = this.getAttribute('data-number');
        busy = true;
        clearTimeout(is_busy);
        if (click !== e.target) {
            busy = false;
        }
        if (change >= text.length - 1 || click !== e.target) {
            change = 0;
            click = e.target;
        } else {
            change = change + 1;
        }
        if (text[0] === '#') {
            input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
            hold = setTimeout(function() {
                input.value = "";
            }, delay);
            return;
        }
        hold = setTimeout(function() {
            input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1) + number;
        }, delay);
        input.value = busy ? input.value.slice(0, -1) + text[change] : input.value + text[change];
    };
    button[i].onmouseup = function(e) {
        clearTimeout(hold);
        busy = true;
        is_busy = setTimeout(function() {
            change = -1;
            busy = false;
            e.target = null;
        }, delay);
        // put caret at the end of text input
        input.focus();
        input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd = input.value.length;
    };
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text">
</p>
<p>
  <button data-text=".,?!'&quot;1-()@/:_" data-number="1">1 <small>o_o</small></button>
  <button data-text="abc2" data-number="2">2 <small>abc</small></button>
  <button data-text="def3" data-number="3">3 <small>def</small></button>
</p>
<p>
  <button data-text="ghi4" data-number="4">4 <small>ghi</small></button>
  <button data-text="jkl5" data-number="5">5 <small>jkl</small></button>
  <button data-text="mno6" data-number="6">6 <small>mno</small></button>
</p>
<p>
  <button data-text="pqrs7" data-number="7">7 <small>pqrs</small></button>
  <button data-text="tuv8" data-number="8">8 <small>tuv</small></button>
  <button data-text="wxyz9" data-number="9">9 <small>wxyz</small></button>
</p>
<p>
  <button data-text=" 0" data-number="0">0 <small>__</small></button>
  <button data-text="#">&larr;</button>
</p>
```

The results are almost in line as I expected, just lacking a few minor things. The following are the requirements:

- Pressing the same button quickly will replace the last character without adding more characters. **OK**
- Switch to another button will add new character. **OK**
- Press and hold the button until `delay` will replace the last character to a number. **OK**
- Pressing the same button quickly will replace the last character without adding more characters, wait until `delay`, then press again. It should add a new character at the end. **NO**

Thank’s for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a keypad as well, you can take some suggestion from it. I did not use the setTimeOut function but I opt-in for a onmouseleave eventListner, so when you leave the div, the last letter that you choise will appear on the display. Also I did not include the numbers yet...still to add stuff, but I hope it will help.

```js
let numbers = new Array(11);
numbers[0] = "1";
numbers[1] = "2";
numbers[2] = "3";
numbers[3] = "4";
numbers[4] = "5";
numbers[5] = "6";
numbers[6] = "7";
numbers[7] = "8";
numbers[8] = "9";
numbers[9] = "*";
numbers[10] = "0";
numbers[11] = "#";

let letter = new Array(11);
letter[0] = "o_o";
letter[1] = "abc";
letter[2] = "def";
letter[3] = "ghi";
letter[4] = "jkl";
letter[5] = "mno";
letter[6] = "pqrs";
letter[7] = "tuv";
letter[8] = "wxyz";
letter[9] = "+";
letter[10] = "_";
letter[11] = "&#8593;";


let text = "";
let counter = 0;
let clicked = false;

// function to create the 12 div ( keypad buttons ). In the div I put the onclick function run() and I assign them a class and Id to style it in CSS.
// also every 3 div, the next div will appear in the second line to create a keypad style.

function start()
{
    
    let div_content ="";
    
    for (i=0; i<=11; i++)
    {
        let element = "number" + i;
        div_content = div_content + '<div class="letter" onclick="run('+i+')" id="'+element+'">'+numbers[i]+'<br>'+letter[i]+'</div>';
        if ((i+1) % 3 ==0) div_content = div_content + '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    }
    
    document.getElementById("key_cont").innerHTML = div_content;
    

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Operating Script//////////////////////////////////////////////////

//function run will be activated when any of the div-button will be pressed, nr function argument will indicate which of the button has been pressed.

function run(nr) {

//for loop to assign addEventListener onmouseleave to all the buttons. it will activate the choiseAndReset function that will show the result on
//the display and will go to the next position in a way to choise another letter.

    for (i=0; i<=11; i++) 
    {
        let element = "number" + i;
        document.getElementById(element).addEventListener("mouseleave", choiseAndReset);
    }

//switch will check which div button has been pressed and will display the correct letter. Inside the cases there are two if.
//one to check the counter ( to check which letter need to be displayed )
//the second one is to check if the capital letter button is clicked, if yes, all the next letters will be Capital letter till will not be deactivated.

    switch (nr) {
  case 0:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 6) {
        
        counter = 1;
        text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,".");
        document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
        //return counter;
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"?");
            document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
        }
        
        else if (counter % 4 == 0){
            text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"!");
            document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
        }
        
        else if (counter % 5 == 0){
            text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"'");
            document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
        }
        
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,",");
            document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
        }
        
        else {
            text += ".";
            document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            
        }
    }
    
    break;
    
  case 1:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 4) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"A");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"a");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"C");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"c");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"B");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"b");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "A";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "a";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
  case 2:
     counter ++;
     
        if(counter >= 4) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"D");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"d");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"F");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"f");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"E");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"e");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "D";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "d";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
  case 3:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 4) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"G");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"g");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"I");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"i");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"H");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"h");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "G";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "g";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
  case 4:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 4) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"J");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"j");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"L");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"l");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"K");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"k");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "J";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "j";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
  case 5:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 4) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"M");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"m");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"O");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"o");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"N");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"n");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "M";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "m";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
  case 6:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 5) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"P");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"p");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"R");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"r");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        
        else if (counter % 4 == 0){
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"S");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"s");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"Q");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"q");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "P";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "p";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            
        }
    }
    break;
  case 7:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 4) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"T");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"t");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"V");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"v");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"U");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"u");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "T";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "t";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
  case 8:
    counter ++;
    
        if(counter >= 5) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"W");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                counter = 1;
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"w");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"Y");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"y");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        
        else if (counter % 4 == 0){
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"Z");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"z");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        
        else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"X");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text = text.toString().replace(/.$/,"x");
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
        }
        
        else {
            if( clicked == true ) {
                text += "W";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            else {
                text += "w";
                document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
            }
            
        }
    }
    break;
  case 9:
    counter ++;
    
    if(counter >= 1) {
        text += "+";
        document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
    }
    
    break;
  case 10:
    counter ++;
    
    if(counter >= 1) {
        text += " ";
        document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
    }
    
    break;
  case 11:
    counter ++;
        if (clicked == true ) {
            clicked = false;
        }
        else {
            clicked = true;
        }
    break;
    
    
}


function choiseAndReset() {
    
    document.getElementById("screen").value = text;
    counter = 0;
    return counter;
    
    
}

//console.log(counter);
//console.log(clicked);
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #253B3B;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
}

p {
    font-size: 35px;
}
#screen {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
}

input[type=text]
{
    color: #979797;
    font-size: 35px;
}

#display {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #BEE5E5;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
}

#key_cont
{
    margin-top: 25px; 
    width: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.letter
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.letter:hover
{
    background-color: #222222;
    color: white;
    border: 5px solid white;
}


#number11:active {     
    background-color:86A3A3;    
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Nokia Keypad</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="keypad.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body onload="start()">
<div class="container">

    <div class="dis" id="display">
        <p><input id="screen" type="text" value="Insert your text"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="key_cont">
    
    </div>
    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="keypad_final.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```